# C floats : how to go around them for 2d geometry (lines)

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, precision, computational-geometry

I am currently doing some 2D geometry in C, mostly lines intersecting themselves. Those lines have all kinds of slopes : from 0.001 to 1000 (examples, I don't even know).

I was using floats until now and did not have to worry about whether the value was very small (and then floating point would store 0,0011 as 1e-3 with no rounding) or very high (and then 1001 would be stored as 1e3), with in both cases little loss of precision where relevant.

But now I want to try without floats, with integers. How to maintain precision in my calculations ? I could have a flag telling me whether the slope is going to be big or small and then consider a tenth of big slopes and ten times small slopes so that rounding is no problem for small slopes and there is no overflow in the case of big slopes. But that feels like a headache.

Basically I need to still be able to differentiate between a slope of 0.2 and 0.4 and also on the overflow side of things a slope of 1000 and 2000 (supposing that ints overflow at 1000 - less of a problem here).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Other than storing both the rise and the run?

Comment: Use a `double` and live with the imprecision? Why would you need more than 15 decimal significant figures of accuracy? That amount of precision is enough to measure the distance from here to Pluto in centimeters.

Comment: You will always have imprecisions when doing computational geometry, because you will always have irrational numbers.

Comment: @DavidBowling Note: all integers and finite floating point values are rational numbers. True that many int/float computations differ from the mathematically result.

Comment: @chux-- Of course. My point was that doing computational geometry in general (in R^n) must involve irrational numbers. For example, a line with slope _m = √2_ can't be represented in slope-intercept form or using direction vectors (i.e., parametric form) without the irrationals. Working with a subset of rational points is one way to avoid these difficulties, but at the cost of limiting objects of inquiry. I think that managing imprecision is unavoidable here; though I suppose it is ultimately a question of goals.

Comment: Why do you want to switch to integers arithmetic ?

Comment: A friend's hardware doesn't have an FPU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the *slope* as a pair of integers

```
struct slope {
  int delta_y;
  int delta_x;
};
```

This allows for a wide range of slopes like `0` and `+/- 1/INT_MAX ... +/- INT_MAX`, even vertical.  With careful coding, exact computations can be had.

Tardy credit: This is much like [@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835993/c-floats-how-to-go-around-them-for-2d-geometry-lines/42836488?noredirect=1#comment72781238_42835993).

Comment: It's a nice idea, especially if you can use a `slope` instance without having to compute the gradient. I might consider making one of the members `unsigned` though, but saying that I guess you could sort out that kind of thing on construction as you might want to "normalise" the input anyway (e.g. {-2, -4} is the same as {1, 2}).

Comment: @Bathsheba Agree about make one field `unsigned` and in `int numerator; unsigned denominator;`.  It make some computations a little tricker though.  `int delta_y, delta_x;` seems to be a good way to introduce the idea to OP.

Comment: You could also get into hot water with unwanted promotion of the signed argument to the type of the unsigned one.

Comment: The OP is making line intersections, and using cross-products is an easy way to avoid the divide-by-zero pitfall in computing a slope. There is an intersection algorithm using cross-products where divide-by-zero can only happen where the lines are parallel, when there is no intersection, a special case which can be tested.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, with lines of arbitrary orientation it is not recommended to work with the slope/intercept representation `y = mx + p`, but with the implicit equation `a x + b y + c = 0`. The latter is more isotropic, supports vertical lines and gives you extra flexibility to scale the coefficients.

Meeting @chux's answer, the coefficients can be the deltas, `Dy x - Dx y + c = 0` (assuming that the lines are defined by two points, `Dx` and `Dy` are likely to not overflow). Overflow is still possible on `c`, and you can use the variant `Dy (x - x0) - Dx (y - y0) = 0`.

Anyway, intermediate computations such as intersections may require larger ranges, i.e. double length integers.

The idea of flagging the large/low value is a little counterproductive: it is actually a primitive way of doing floating-point, i.e. separating the scale from the mantissa. Working this way, you will somehow re-design a foating-point system, less powerful than the built-in type and costing you sweat and tears.

---

Unfortunately, high range arithmetic can't be avoided. Indeed, the intersection of two straight lines is given by the Cramer formulas

```
x = (c b' - c' b) / (a b' - a' b),
y = (a c' - a' c) / (a b' - a' b)
```

where the products to be evaluated are one order of magnitude larger than the initial coefficients. This is explained by the fact that quasi-parallel lines have far-away intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Look up *[fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)* if you want to use int in a general way.

You can also design your algorithms so that you do every computation in such a way that you don't need sub-integer accuracy (for example look up [Bresenham's line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) and [circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) drawing algorithms).

To your particular problem, you could try to keep quotient and fraction separately, in other words use rational numbers. Or ot put it another way, have delta X and delta Y as two numbers.